# How to install packages under ROS

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install packages from the URL: http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php?package_type=package&distro=groovy
but failed for many times. I don't know how to use the apt-get to install a package from that web.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196766/how-to-install-packages-under-ros/) by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-11-05**:
which package you want to install, first get source by git clone and then build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For released packages you just type:

> sudo apt-get install ros-"your ros
> distro"-"package-name"

If you use ROS indigo and want to install the package image-view you just do

> sudo apt-get install
> ros-indigo-image-view

If the package is not released then you will need to install it from source code, click on the name of the package on the package's list page and find out where the code is hosted (mostly github), clone the package's repository in your workspace. then catkin_make. This is explained in detail in beginner's tutorials.

Now the problem with installing from source code is that you have to take care of the dependencies by yourself. whenever you see "Could not find a configuration file for package xxxxx" it means this package is missing and is needed for compiling your code. You could also try using [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/rosdep)  which will automatically try to find all the dependencies of your package and install them.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on 2014-11-05**:
Thanks very much! I have tried it before (http://answers.ros.org/question/195703/question-in-install-third-party-package-on-ros/) , there's some problems when i tried to catkin_make. I don't know how to solve it.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-11-05**:
I edited my answer.

**Comment by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on 2014-11-06**:
thx a lot ! i solved that error, I think I used to download the wrong package!